# UITableViewCell Circle Bullet Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, geometry, cgrect

I've been trying to implement colorful circle bullet points like in the iOS Calendar app.

[image: selection view]

I'd like to have cells with the circles in front of the textLabel like the image above.

[image: selected view]

And I'd also like to have the corresponding circle in front of the detailTextLabel like the image above.

I've tried to do this with an image inside a frame but it is always too big. Plus, the circles in the Calendar app don't appear to be in the imageView of the cell.

I've also tried drawing a circle with some code I found from another question. This code isn't working for me though. Here's code from my XYZCircleView.m file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    //CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(1, 1, self.frame.size.width - 2,    self.frame.size.height - 2));
}
```

And inside my `cellForRow...`:

```
CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(10,10,10,10);
XYZCircleView *circleView = [[XYZCircleView alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
[cell.contentView addSubview:circleView];
```

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a bullet character and use an attributed string so you can set the color of the bullet.

Something like this:

```
NSString *text = @"• Calendar";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] };
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]; // color the bullet
[attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(1, attrStr.length - 1)]; // color the rest

cell.text.attributedText = attrStr;
```

You may need to use a different font or colors as needed.

Comment: Even though I have used rounak's solution in many places (with an additional border that seems invisible), I prefer this solution. More elegant, in my opinion. Exactly the same thing that hit me first.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very simple solution. Does the `NSFontAttributeName` part determine the bullet size? Or how can I make it bigger?

Comment: The font applies to the whole string. Try different bullet characters such as ∙ or • or ・ or ● or ⬤ or ⚫︎.

Comment: I guess I should have stated that you could apply two difference fonts to the different parts of the string just like the colors. But using a bigger bullet is easier if it fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding a square view as a subview to the cell and set its layer's `cornerRadius` property to make it into a circle.

Comment: How will this work for the 2nd cell where the color and calendar name need to appear in the `detailTextLabel` of the cell?

Comment: Maybe you need a table view cell subclass where you can layout your own views based on your needs